# When does a += b become a = a + b in Scala?

Tags: scala, assignment-operator, syntactic-sugar

Scala only *sometimes* desugars

```
a += b
```

to

```
a = a + b
```

but not always. For example, some mutable collections define a `+=` method, where instead it becomes

```
a.+=(b)
```

Is this behaviour

1. entirely determined by whether there is a suitable `+=` method on `a`? (incl. are there any other examples of this behaviour?)
2. independent of whether the objects are val or var?

**Relevant example**

Adapted from *Programming in Scala*, in

```
var s = Set("a", "b")
s += "c"
```

> In this case, the second line of code `s += "c"` is essentially shorthand for:

```
s = s + "c"
```

Comment: Note: what "Scala" is / means is defined in the Scala Language Specification. Answers to questions like yours can always be found there, and they are *by definition* the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When does a += b become a = a + b in Scala?

When there is no applicable `+=` method, there *is* an applicable `+` method and `a` is assignable (that is, it's a `var` or there's an `a_=` method).

Or as [the spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators) puts it:

> The re-interpretation occurs if the following two conditions are fulfilled.
>
> 1. The left-hand-side `l` does not have a member named `+=`, and also cannot be converted by an implicit conversion to a value with a member named `+=`.
> 2. The assignment `l = l + r` is type-correct. In particular this implies that `l` refers to a variable or object that can be assigned to, and that is convertible to a value with a member named `+`.

---

> Is this behaviour
>
> 1. entirely determined by whether there is a suitable += method on a?
> 2. independent of whether the objects are val or var?

Not quite. If there is a suitable `+=` method, it will be called regardless of any other factors (such as `a` being assignable). But when there isn't, the other factors determine whether it's desugared or you get an error message.

Note that the error message you get is different than the one you'd get from the desugared version: When the criteria for the desugaring don't apply, you get an error message that tells you "+= is not a member of ...", plus an explanation why the desugaring couldn't be applied (such as "receiver is not assignable" or the type error you'd get from `a + b` if `a + b` would produce a type error).

Answer (score 0):

In my first answer I was a little hasty, my apologies. After researching a little and after read better the @sepp2k's answer and comment, I came to the conclusion that some classes in Scala implements the `+=` method, and other just the `+` method, I played a little in With some Scala code and for instance:

```
  //Set, Int, Double, String implements the "+" method,
  //and then "+=" is syntactic sugar of a = a + b 
  var set = Set("a", "b")
  set += "c"

  var num = 3
  num += 2

  var str = "43"
  str += 5

  var l = List()
  l += "someString"

  // As you mention, MutableList implements "+=" method, and when you do
  // mutL += 4, is the same as call the method mutL.+=
  var mutL = new mutable.MutableList[Int]
  mutL += 4
```